# Catch error from function within external script

Tags: javascript, soundcloud

I'm working with the Soundcloud API, but this question is about catching errors in general.

I try to load a track, and, due to some settings or restrictions specific to that track, get a `403 (Forbidden)` response. This error is thrown within the soundcloud script which I'm loading in my `<head>`:

`<script src="https://connect.soundcloud.com/sdk/sdk-3.1.2.js"></script>`

Later, in my client-side javascript:

```
SC.initialize({
    client_id: 'xxxx',
});
...
SC.resolve(`https://soundcloud.com/${trackUrl}`).then((response) => {
    this.track.setAttribute('src', `${response.stream_url}?client_id=xxxx`);
});
```

**trackURL** is a valid URL - it's the 'readable' url of the track, and it *is* resolving to the correct track ID, which I can see in the GET request error below:

In the console:

`api.js:26 GET https://api.soundcloud.com/tracks/276705791.json?client_id=20f6b95488a0ca8f2254e250e6b0b229 403 (Forbidden)`

```
inspecting api.js:
const sendRequest = (method, url, data, progress) => {
  let xhr;
  const requestPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
    const isFormData = global.FormData && (data instanceof FormData);
    xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    if (xhr.upload) {
      xhr.upload.addEventListener('progress', progress);
    }
    xhr.open(method, url, true);

    if (!isFormData) {
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    }

    xhr.onreadystatechange = () => {
      if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
        resolve({responseText: xhr.responseText, request: xhr});
      }
    };

    xhr.send(data); // <-- LINE 26
  });

  requestPromise.request = xhr;
  return requestPromise;
};
```

Since I'm loading this script externally, I can't fuss with it.

Is there any way to watch for errors within my own javascript so I can prepare a fallback?

**Update**

Joseph's answer below is what I needed - to look for the error in the `resolve` promise. Soundcloud isn't too helpful with response messages, but I can now program a fallback. Updated code:

```
    SC.resolve('https://soundcloud.com/jacquesgreene/you-cant-deny').then((response) => {
        this.track.setAttribute('src', `${response.stream_url}?client_id=20f6b95488a0ca8f2254e250e6b0b229`);
        this.element.addClass('ready');
    }, (error) => {
        myFallback();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest answer would be to consult the documentation.

Now this is XHR, which is asynchronous. You can't "catch" with your regular `try-catch`.

The xhr operation, however, only checks for readyState 4. means the xhr completed regardless of the HTTP status, even 403, and just resolves the promise with the data (`responseText`) and the xhr object itself (`xhr`). The problem now is if that resolved value goes back to your `SC.resolve` call.

From here, it's all a wild guess (unless, again, you consult the documentation). You can either inspect what `response` is in your callback, or try adding a reject callback in your call hope the API mapped it correctly as a failure.

```
SC.resolve(`https://soundcloud.com/${trackUrl}`).then((response) => {
    // What is `response` and what does it contain?
}, function(error){
    // Does this execute? If so, what is `arguments`.
});
```

Comment: Thanks joseph, see my update above. logging the `error` to the console doesn't give me much info: `{ message: "HTTP Error: 403", status: 403 }` but now I can move ahead with a fallback.